# Video Player to play Video from SD Card

Tags: android, android-video-player

Found Jiecao Video Player, here is the [link](https://github.com/xuwt/jiecaovideoplayer) of that one and able to play video using online URL.

```
JCFullScreenActivity.toActivity(this,
    "http://2449.vod.myqcloud.com/2449_43b6f696980311e59ed467f22794e792.f20.mp4",
    JCVideoPlayerStandard.class,
    "Title");
```

But, What If I have to play a Video from SD Card, like: `toystory.mp4` (available in **Download** folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your `AndroidManifest`

and
use this

```
String fileName = "YourVideo.mp4"; //your file name in downloads folder
        String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + fileName; //your file path

        //File file = new File(completePath);
        //Uri video = Uri.fromFile(file);
JCFullScreenActivity.toActivity(this,
    completePath,
    JCVideoPlayerStandard.class,
    "Title");
```

> I analysed github code and found that it's just using `MediaPlayer`
>   and passing uri to it.

Comment: In my program only single activity I am using (i.e. MainActivity) and playing video by default in a Full Screen as you can see in my code... but on back press unable to exit my Activity... WHY ? Still its just exiting from Full Screen Mode not closing Activity...

Comment: can you post your log?

Comment: Please check this: http://pastebin.com/zJ7Eb4ZK and here is the code: http://pastebin.com/Kz9yRmaN